# HTTPURLConnection.getContent java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, httpurlconnection

I use a `HttpURLConnection` to connect to a website and receive an `ResponseCode=404 (HTTP_NOT_FOUND)`. However I have no problem opening the website in my browser (IE).

Why the difference, and what can I do about it?

This is my Program:

```
String responseMsg = "";

String cgsUrl = "http://localhost:9081/ntes/";

URL url = new URL(cgsUrl);
System.out.println("ouuuuuuu-->"+url.getContent());

InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();

StringBuffer respDataBuf = new StringBuffer();
respDataBuf.setLength(0);
int b = -1;

while((b = in.read()) != -1) {
    respDataBuf.append((char)b);
}
responseMsg = respDataBuf.toString();
```

Comment: Do you use a servlet on the server side? Does it accept both get and post requests?

Comment: Could you show us the error stack trace, please?

Comment: Does it work without  System.out.println("ouuuuuuu-->"+url.getContent());
?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a 404 error, this is certainly a particular server configuration.

Maybe your user-agent is banned, or you're not carrying  special headers and so on. I recommend you copying the headers from your browser (all of them) and use them to make the request in your Java program.

Then you throw them away one by one to find the one which is mandatory